# combine some elements from 2 txt files into a third file

Tags: java, file

I have two files Persons.txt and Hobby.txt.In the third file i want to put all the persons names and add each name some hobbies.This is how my files look like
Persons.txt

```
ID;NUME;PRENUME;DATA_NASTERII;PROFESIA
1;Stan;Ilie;22-01-1977;profesor;
2;Becali;GG;01-07-1965;patron;
3;Tanase;Cristian;07-12-1988;fotbalist;
4;Pop;Ion;21-03-1984;pictor;
5;Popescu;Rodica;17-04-1986;sculptor;
```

Hobby.txt

```
ID;NUME;DESCRIERE;NUMAR_MINIM_PERSOANE;ELEMENT_NECESAR
1;baschet;sport in care se arunca mingea la cos;6;minge
2;fotbal;sport in care nue voie sa atingi mingea in poarta adversa;14;minge
3;chitara;cantatul la chitara;1;chitara
4;pianul; cantatul la pian;1;pian
5;programarea;scrierea de programe software;1;PC
```

I need a third file that looks like this:

```
Ion Pop : baschet, volei
Ilie Stan: steaua, handbal
```

The problem is that i don't know

- how to get the persons name and
- how to append to them 2 or three hobbies.
- how to split each line from the file and write to the third file

My code

```
   import java.io.*;
   import java.util.*;
   import java.util.ArrayList;

   public class ListaHobby {
             String line="";
             Persoana p = new Persoana();
             Hobby h = new Hobby();
             public void writeListaHobbies(){
               try{
                     FileReader file1 =new FileReader("Persoane.txt");
                     Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("Persoane.txt"));
                     ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
                     System.out.println(values.size());

                     FileReader file2 = new FileReader("Hobby.txt");
                     scan = new Scanner(new File("Hobby.txt"));
                     values = new ArrayList<String>();
                     System.out.println(values.size());

                     while(scan.hasNext()){
                               values.add(scan.next());
                     }

                      BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(file1);
                      BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(file2);

                      String temp1="";
                      String temp2="";

                      while(br1.readLine() != null){
                        temp1 = br1.readLine() + temp1;
                      }
                      while(br2.readLine() != null){
                            temp2 = br2.readLine() + temp2;
                      }

                      String temp = temp1 + temp2;

                       FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("PersHobby.txt");
                       char buffer[] = new char[temp.length()];
                       temp.getChars(0, temp.length(), buffer, 0);
                       fw.write(buffer);
                       file1.close();
                       file2.close();
                       fw.close();
                    }
                    catch(IOException ex){
                           System.out.println("Error opening file.");
                           System.exit(1);
                    }`
```

Comment: Study `FileUtils` (http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html), especially methods `readLines()` and `writeLines()`. Splitting a line into tokens can be done with `String#split(String)` method (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

Comment: Are you trying to randomly assign one or more Hobby to each Person?

Comment: How to assign a hobby to a person ? is it based on Ids ?

Comment: i have no idea how to assign more hobbies to a person

Comment: @Laura : If you do not have a clear requirement , i say base it on the Ids. That will push you to a solution

Comment: @Laura have a look at my edit. a person has simple a list of hobbies. you can add as many as you want to. and note the wording: set or add. set is just one, add is a new on to many others.

Answer (score 3):

Try to see it from an object oriented point of view. You have to objects. A `Person` object and somthing like a `Hobby` object. Each line of your files represent one such object. What you should do now is to parse the files like you do, but create objects with the information. Assuming that `br1` is the reader for file 1 it could look like this:

```
while(br1.readLine() != null){

    String line = br1.readLine();           // read the line
    String[] attributes = line.split(";");  // split it at every ";"

    Person person = new Person();           // make a new person
    person.setName(attributes[0]);          
    person.setSurname(attributes[1]);
    person.setDate(attributes[2]);
    person.setProfession(attributes[3]);

    listOfPersons.add(person);               // store the person in a list
}
```

Of course, you have to create a Person class as well as a Hobby class.

After that you can iterate trough you lists and search for the Hobbies of a person. If you found one, add it to the person:

```
for(Person person: listOfPersons) {

    for(Hobby hobby: listOfHobbies) {

        if(person.getId().equals(hobby.getPerson()))
            person.addHobby(hobby);
     }
 }
```

After that you have a list of persons with their hobbies. You can write this to a file again. This approach needs a little bit more code, but mostly simple code. And you do it in a clean way.

EDIT:

A Person class could look like this:

public class Person {

```
private int id;
private String name;
private String surname;
private String date;
private String profession;

private List<Hobby> hobbies = new ArrayList<Hobby>();

// getter & setter for all this attributes

// here is the one to add hobbies:
public void addHobby(Hobby hobby) {

    hobbies.add(hobby);
}
}
```

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer it really helped.i am new to java and oop i have created the Person and Hobby classes but when i write this code if(person.getId().equals(hobby.getPerson())) 
            person.addHobby(hobby); it says that int int cannot be dereferenced .What is that?

Comment: @Laura sorry I missed that. "int" is primitive type, whereas "Integer" is a real class. Every class has a equals method to compare it to others.  A primitive doesn't have such a method (or any  method, that's why it's called primitive). So you can to two things: (1) replace int with Integer or (2) remove the equals and use simple == (person.getId() == hobby.getPerson()). Vote up and mark the answer as correct when I helped you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To generate a file PersHobby.txt as you have defined in your question the following actions need be taken

- Read names from Person list
- Read hobbies from Hobby list
- Run a loop for each person in the list
- Run a loop to generate a random selection of hobbies
- Create a line such of current person and above hobbies
- Write above line to PersHobby

The above algorithm is very tentative.

Since the structure of each file is similar (semi-colon separated), we may read just the relevant field as follows

```
private static List<String> readFieldFromFile(List<String> values, String delimiter, int index) {

    if (values != null && values.size() > 0) {

        List<String> returnable = new ArrayList<String>(values.size());
        // proceed only if the list of values is non-empty
        Iterator<String> it = values.iterator();
        // instantiate an iterator
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            // iterate over each line
            String currLine = it.next();
            if (currLine != null && currLine.trim().length() > 0) {
                // split the line into it's constituent fields if the line is not empty
                String[] fields = currLine.split(delimiter);
                if (fields.length - index > 0) // Read the particular field, and store it into the returnable
                {
                    returnable.add(fields[index - 1]);
                }
            }
        }
        return returnable;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

public static List<String> readName(List<String> persons) {
// name occurs at the second position in the line
    return readFieldFromFile(persons, ";", 2);
}

public static List<String> readHobby(List<String> hobbies) {
// name of hobby occurs at the second position in the line
    return readFieldFromFile(hobbies, ";", 2);
}
```

Next we need to generate a string for hobbies of a person .. something like the method below. This method plucks two hobbies at random from the collection of hobbies thrown at it.

```
public static String generateRandomHobbies(List<String> hobbies){
    String hobbieString = "";
    // Read two hobbies at random from the hobbies list into a comma-separated string
    if(hobbies.size() >= 2){
        Random rand = new Random();
        hobbieString.concat( hobbies.get((int)(hobbies.size()*rand.nextFloat())) );
        hobbieString.concat( ", " );
        hobbieString.concat( hobbies.get((int)(hobbies.size()*rand.nextFloat())) );
        hobbieString.concat( ", " );
    }
    return hobbieString;
}
```

Hopefully this shall prove to be sufficient. I leave the formatting of strings, and actually writing into the output file to you.

p.s. Your existing code to use the scanner is faulty as objects re-initialize. This re-initialization would leave the application with only the contents of the Hobby file.

```
while(scan.hasNext()){
    values.add(scan.next());
}
```

Please fix this issue so the content from each file is in a separate List.